# Separate declaration and definition in .h and .cpp but NON-class functions?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have the practice of writing functions that do not have to be in a class in namespaces, so I would like to know if can separate them in source and headers files:

utilities.hpp:

```
namespace nms {
    static void process();
};
```

utilities.cpp

```
void nms::process(){/*...*/}
```

But like this I only get an error: `main.cpp:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to 'nms::process()'`. So i would like to know if this is possible in anyway.

Comment: Remove `static`.

Comment: @user17732522 oh, so simple and correct

Comment: Why did you put it there in the first place?

Comment: @user17732522 sounds logic to me until now. In this case, will `process` be compiled only once?

Comment: @JonnasKaf Assuming that you compile `utilities.cpp` only once, then yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the header file `utilities.hpp`:

```
namespace nms {
    static void process();
};
```

`static` means the function has *internal* linkage, meaning it *declares* a unique function for each translation unit in which the header is included.

The only translation unit (TU) for which the corresponding unique (internal linkage) `process()` function has a *definition* is, however, in the TU associated with `utilities.cpp`, whereas for any other source file which includes `utilities.hpp`, no definition exists for the TU-local `process()` function.

This explains why you get undefined reference errors in locations other than `utilities.cpp`, as soon as that use site requires a definition for the TU-local function. Remove static and the publically-intended `process()` function will not have internal linkage.

---

> ... but NON-class functions?

The `static` keyword is unfortunately quite overloaded in meaning in C++, and `static` for class member function does not mean the same thing as for a namespace scope function as `process()` above. For class member function, using the `static` keyword makes the *static* members ([[class.static]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.static).